# Persistent HTML outside of jQuery Mobile Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to include a bit of HTML outside of the `<div data-role="page">` element on my main page. This HTML shouldn't be replaced when a new page is loaded in via ajax.

The example application for this is to have a small absolutely positioned div in the top-right that is only displayed upon errors related to AJAX calls, or status updates with the application.

If I try and include any HTML in the body of my index.html page, it gets replaced by jQuery Mobile immediately. I don't want to have to include this div on each and every page I write.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some abridged HTML and JS sample code to your question that demonstrates the problem?  It would make it easier to understand exactly what is going on.  Just the body and the JS itself would be fine.  If the demo repros on jsfiddle.net (not sure for jQuery mobile samples), you could additionally provide a link to a fiddle.

Comment: Mike, instead of putting the new html code outside the div, You could use two "Main" divs, do your ajax stuff and jQuery magic in one of them and load your new html via jQuery on it and the other div should remain the same. Still need more info on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `div`s get replaced. For example, this will bring the first unseen `div` to the top:

http://jsfiddle.net/RQkrj/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
.top {
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
<script>
$('div#page').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    $('div#doesNotGetRemoved').addClass("top");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="doesNotGetRemoved" style="background: red; position: absolute;">This is a div</div>

<div id="page" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>Hello world</p>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pages are not replaced in JQuery Mobile. They are with JQTouch. I think you could/should just make your div an extra page. I have added divs in to the html before (not as pages) and it caused strange rendering when I updated to new versions of JQMobile. I haven't tried with the latest.