# Hitting page reload/refresh in jquery mobille

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having trouble understanding what happens when the user reloads/refreshes a page in a jquery mobile application.What I am observing is that for every page in an app, clicking refresh/reload triggers $(document).ready() function but nothing else is triggered?Can anyone suggest what exactly happens and how to handle this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean '*nothing else is triggered*'? What do you expect to be triggered.

Comment: I expect 'pageshow' to be triggered.I am adding dynamic content to the page via pageshow event and if I click refresh button,all dynamic content is removed.

Comment: Try this answer and see if your events are set up in the same way. The pageshow in the example executes on page reload - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513243/persistent-html-outside-of-jquery-mobile-pages#8513391.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, its working.The issue seems to be that you have to attach the handler to 'pageshow' outside the $(document).ready function and with 'live',not 'bind',otherwise it won,t be called when the user clicks refresh.Also, $(document).ready is called every time the user clicks refresh.

Comment: Ok, I'll add an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer and see if your events are set up in the same way. The pageshow in the example executes on page reload.

[Persistent HTML outside of jQuery Mobile Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513243/persistent-html-outside-of-jquery-mobile-pages#8513391)